Pocket Wizard trigger solenoid
I'm looking to trigger a 12 V solenoid (Johnson Electric 174432-024) using a Pocket Wizard (normally used to synchronize and trigger cameras). When the Pocket Wizard is in receiving mode, it measures at a constant 3.11 V. Then, when the Pocket Wizard is is triggered, the voltage drops to 0 V.
Is there a way to cycle the solenoid using the signal from the Pocket Wizard? I imagine if the voltage on the Pocket Wizard went from 0 V to 3 V instead of 3 V to 0 V, then I could just use a solid-state relay with the solenoid connected to a power supply. I'm not sure what to do since the voltage drops to 0 V when triggered. Is this possible without using an Arduino or a microcontroller?

Are you able to connect the grounds for the solenoid power supply and the pocket wizard? I assume so since you were able to measure voltage, but is it easily accessible to you?

I don't see why not? Currently the solenoid is powered by an AC/DC adapter. The pocket wizard uses a 3.5mm mono miniphone plug (which yeah, ive cut to measure voltage).

The standard for camera shutter trigger and flash trigger interfaces is a contact closure to ground, not a voltage. A long time ago it was a mechanical contact. Now, it is a transistor or occasionally an SCR.
The trigger plus signal will be the center pin.
Why you are measuring 3.1 volts is a little puzzling. Was the camera connected when you measured this voltage?
This circuit should work. Use a V+ of no more than 12 V. Keep the current below 20 mA. You may want to run some tests with just a resistor to V+. Measure with a scope.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

No cameras are connected to the Pocket Wizards. They are powered by two AA batteries. The Pocket Wizard has a 3.5mm headphone jack on the side, and when powered on i'm measuring 3.1 V across the 3.5mm cable with a multimeter.

Then, when the Pocket Wizard is triggered, the voltage across the headphone jack drops to zero.
